# Unable to submit C# code from compiler into SO

Tags: support, code-formatting

I have tried the following, copying my code from the IDE into SO. Copying the code and verfied that it is indented 4 spaces as requested by SO and then pasting into SO. I also went as far as to hand type everything from IDE into the SO manually building the code and it still gave me the below error. I could not find any good help to get past this error message and submit my code. I have tried to alter the format several ways. Thank you greatly for your assistance.
[image]

Comment: It looks as though the opening few lines are not indented. `public class DebugFight3 {` needs to be included in the code block as well.

Comment: You should also remove "Thank you for your time!"

Comment: from what the image is showing you haven't done what the error message suggests. the first 2 lines of your code won't format correctly because there isn't 4 spaces. also i should note that there you start a paragraph with a new line and a space, this wont render correctly on screen, you need 2 spaces in-between paragraphs otherwise they appear as just one paragraph

Comment: Thank you. It was the space between the paragraphs that prevented the submission.